# WebView not launching new tab with external URL whatsapp

Tags: kotlin, webview

I have a WebView that opens a website url.
But on this website there is a WhatsApp button, when clicking on it it gives the error:
net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
Would there be a way to open the external link?
How do I fix this error?

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        if ((activity.applicationInfo.flags and ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE) != 0) {
            WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true)
        }
        webView.webViewClient = WebViewClient() // handle redirects in the app
        webView.webChromeClient = webChromeClient
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(AppInterface(), "appInterface")
        val webSettings = webView.settings
        webSettings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webSettings.domStorageEnabled = true
        webSettings.databaseEnabled = true
        webSettings.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture = false
        val url = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(activity)
            .getString(MainActivity.PREFERENCE_URL, null)
        if (url != null) {
            webView.loadUrl(url)
        } else {
            activity.fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, StartFragment())
                .commitAllowingStateLoss()
        }
    }
```